# ¿porque me sale este error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" si tengo la componente definida?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo mi componente definida en moviesTable.jsx `<TableBody data = {this.props.movies} />` y en tableBody.jsx uso la funcion map anidandola, es decir dos veces uso map pero no se porque me dice undefined, no veo que mi codigo este mal, ya busque en otros foros y decian que debia definirla con this.props, pero yo si la tengo definida, no creo que sea porque la uso dos veces puesto que tengo una tabla asique no se que es lo que esta mal realmente, el error me marca la linea 21 donde empieza el primer map.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

class TableBody extends Component {
   renderCell = (item, column) => {
       if(column.content) return column.content(item);

       return _.get(item, column.path);
   }

   createKey = (item, column) => {
       return item._id + (column.path || column.key);
   }
   
    render() { 
        const { data, columns } = this.props;

        return ( 
            <tbody>
               {data.map(item => (
                <tr key = {item._id}>
                    {columns.map(column => <td key = {this.createKey(item, column)}>{this.renderCell(item, column)}</td>)}
                </tr>))}
            </tbody>
         );
    }
}
 
export default TableBody;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es cierto que no estaba definiendo las columnas `<TableBody data = {this.props.movies} columns = {this.columns} />` esto si me funciona!!